# XSLT to remove XML tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with an XML structure which should be modified to perform some actions on it.

This is the XML structure which is to be modified from :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Header>
      <OrgId>20000000</OrgId>
   </Header>
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter>
         <value>I21</value>
         <name>ELEMENT_TYPE</name>
      </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   <ResponseListener>
      <URI>https://..................../</URI>
      <Method>POST</Method>
   </ResponseListener>
   <System>USER</System>
   <ElementId>Tets001</ElementId>
   <ElementDesc>
      <Id>d2U201</Id>
      <Date>2018-02-20T00:00:00</Date>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <ElementId>1</ElementId>
      <Action>
         <TransactionName>ABC</TransactionName>
         <ElementSpecification>
            <Name>EQUIPMENT</Name>
            <Version>1.22</Version>
            <Parameters>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>270</value>
                  <name>MATERIAL_ID_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>203</value>
                  <name>QUANTITY_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>ZYXEL</value>
                  <name>MATERIAL_NAME_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>VK40</value>
                  <name>PLANT_ID</name>
               </Parameter>
            </Parameters>
         </ElementSpecification>
      </Action>
   </ElementDesc>
</root>
```

to this below structure:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Header>
      <OrgId>20000000</OrgId>
   </Header>
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter>
         <value>I21</value>
         <name>ELEMENT_TYPE</name>
      </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   <ResponseListener>
      <URI>https://..................../</URI>
      <Method>POST</Method>
   </ResponseListener>
   <System>USER</System>
   <ElementId>Tets001</ElementId>
   <ElementDesc>
      <Id>d2U201</Id>
      <Date>2018-02-20T00:00:00</Date>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <ElementId>1</ElementId>
      <Action>
         <TransactionName>ABC</TransactionName>
         <ElementSpecification>
            <Name>EQUIPMENT</Name>
            <Version>1.22</Version>

               <Parameter>
                  <value>270</value>
                  <name>MATERIAL_ID_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>203</value>
                  <name>QUANTITY_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>ZYXEL</value>
                  <name>MATERIAL_NAME_1</name>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <value>VK40</value>
                  <name>PLANT_ID</name>
               </Parameter>

         </ElementSpecification>
      </Action>
   </ElementDesc>
</root>
```

Which xslt should I use to achieve this? I have tried with below xslt but it did not result the desired results.

The XSLT is as below:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="m0 fn"> 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ProductSpecification/Parameters">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of

```
<xsl:template match="//ProductSpecification/Parameters">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

you want

```
<xsl:template match="ProductSpecification/Parameters">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```